# React navigation pass initial route to createappContainer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

How do I pass the initial route props in react navigation v.3? In v.2 I use to export default a drawer like this

```
export default ({ initialRouteName }) => {
  return createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      AnimeStack,
      TvStack,
      FilmStack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: initialRouteName
    }
  );
};
```

meaning that if I passed an object with the initial route it would render that screen first. I tried to implement that in the v.3 like this

```
const DrawerNavigation = ({ initialRouteName }) => {
  return createDrawerNavigator(
    {
      AnimeStack,
      TvStack,
      FilmStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: initialRouteName ,
    }
  );
};
const MainTabNaigator = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigation);
export default MainTabNaigator;
```

but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To export default 'DrawerNavigator' should be like this.

```
const AnimeStack = createStackNavigator (
{
    Home: AnimationController,
}, {
    intialRouteName: "Home",
})

const RootStack = createDrawerNavigator({
    Animations: AnimeStack,
    TVs: TvStack,
    Films: FilmStack,
}, {
    intialRouteName: 'Animations',
});

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```